# Determine the sign of $\int_0^{2\pi}f(x)dx$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis

$f(0)=1$, $f(x)=\frac{\sin(x)}{x}$ for $x>0$

I know that the sign of this integral is positive because for $0\leq x\leq\pi$ the area between the curve and x axis is larger than the area between the curve and x axis for $\pi\leq x\leq 2\pi$. This is obvious when looking at the graph of $f(x)$ but I'm unsure how to prove this rigorously. Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: $$\int_0^{2\pi} f(x)\,dx = \int_0^\pi f(x) + f(x+\pi)\,dx$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Filling in Daniel's hint: Let's split the integral into two parts --
$$
\int_0^{2\pi} \frac{\sin x}{x} dx = \int_0^{\pi} \frac{\sin x}{x} dx 
+ \int_\pi^{2\pi} \frac{\sin x}{x} dx = \int_0^{\pi} \frac{\sin x}{x} dx + \int_0^{\pi} \frac{\sin (v+\pi)}{v+\pi} dv
$$
Re-substituting $x$ for the dummy $v$ and re-combining, using the fact that $\sin(x+\pi) = -\sin x$, we get
$$
\int_0^{2\pi} \frac{\sin x}{x} dx = \int_0^{\pi} \sin x \left( \frac{1}{x} - \frac{1}{x+\pi} \right) dx
$$
which is the integral of a function which is always positive, so the integral is positive.

Answer (score 0):

You could use that $\sin(x + \pi) = -\sin(x)$. So you would have that
$$
\left\lvert \frac{\sin(x)}{x}\right\rvert > \left\lvert\frac{\sin(x)}{x+\pi}\right\rvert = \left\lvert\frac{\sin(x+\pi)}{x+\pi}\right\rvert
$$
for $x\in (0, \pi]$. 
So
$$
\int_{0}^{2\pi}\frac{\sin(x)}{x} = \int_0^{\pi} \frac{\sin(x)}{x}\; dx + \int_{\pi}^{2\pi} \frac{\sin(x)}{x}\; dx = \dots
$$